# I can't find the Runtime error(NZEC) in this java program

Tags: java, runtime-error

I can't find the Runtime error(NZEC) in this java program.This program is running in CodeChef Compiler but it's give Runtime error whenever I submit the code.
I can't find the Runtime error(NZEC) in this java program.This program is running in CodeChef Compiler but it's give Runtime error whenever I submit the code.

Link of a question -> [enter link description here](https://www.codechef.com/problems/RAINBOWA)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=s.nextInt();
    s.nextLine();
    for(int te=0;te<t;te++){
        int n=s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine();
        int[] strArray = new int[n];


        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            strArray[i] = s.nextInt();          

        int flag=0;
        int done=0;

        if(strArray[0] == 1){
            int bf = 1;

            for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {

                if(strArray[i] == 7){
                    if(strArray[i+1] > 7){
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }else{
                        if(strArray[i+1] == 6){
                            done=1;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }

                if(strArray[i] == bf || (strArray[i]-1) == bf){
                    bf = strArray[i];
                    continue;
                }else{
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("no");
        }

        if(flag ==1 ){
            System.out.println("no");
        }
        else{
            if(done==1){

                int l=0,r=strArray.length-1;
                int cflag=0;
                while(strArray[l]==strArray[r]){
                    l++;r--;
                    if(l==r){
                        cflag=1;
                        System.out.println("yes");
                        break;
                    }

                }
                if(cflag!=1){
                    System.out.println("no");
                }

            }
        }   

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and test your code for an input like:

> ```
> n = 5;
> strArray = {1,3,5,6,7};
> ```

```
if(strArray[0] == 1){
    int bf = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {  
        if(strArray[i] == 7) {
            if(strArray[i+1] > 7) // what would happen here? what is i+1?
```

Probably you shall realize better now how to fix it.